# Java - How to sort a Set<Entry<K,V>>?

Tags: java, json, sorting, set, key

I have the following Set, having a json string.

```
Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = jsonObject.entrySet();
```

I want to have this list sorted by key, but I'm stuck here. You'd suggest a way to sort, or a better way to use the JSON?

My purposes:

```
for(Entry entry : entrySet) {
  if( !"sign".equals(entry.getKey()) ){         
    JsonElement elemValue = jsonObject.get((String) entry.getKey());
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair((String) entry.getKey(), elemValue.getAsString()));
  } 
}
```

That's my first question, so I apologize and thank you all for the patience.

Comment: Do these entries come from a map of some sort? If so, you could make it a `TreeMap` and get the entries sorted by key values automatically.

Comment: @csharpfolk I wonder how `Entry` will be sorted if you don't assign a `Comparator`.

Comment: @KeqiangLi you are right, I removed my comment

Comment: @MickMnemonic It's JsonObject of Google's lib, Gson:
public final class JsonObject extends JsonElement {
  private final LinkedTreeMap<String, JsonElement> members =
      new LinkedTreeMap<String, JsonElement>();
      [...]
      public Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet() {
         return members.entrySet();
      }
      [...]
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple comparator and streams to achieve this:

```
    entrySet.stream().sorted((e1, e2) -> e1.getKey().compareTo(e2.getKey())).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Obviously if you only want to iterate over it, you do not have to collect it. (You might also want to use the value for the comparison in case the keys are equals, though that was not mentioned in your question.)

I assumed you have no null value(s) neither in the set, nor in the keys.

Edit: Thanks to @JornVernee for pointing out that there is already a `Comparator` for `Map#Entry`s. Using that, it would look like this (`collect` is still optional in case you just want to iterate through them; you can also specify a different comparator for the keys too with a slightly different syntax):

```
    entrySet.stream().sorted(Entry.comparingByKey(/*Comparator<String> if needed*/))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Tip: you can use ```Map.Entry.comparingByKey()```, as a comparator.

Comment: Worked out! Thanks! 
I figured out a way to sort the postParameters, after the For, which was a good solution too. 
`Collections.sort(postParameters, new Comparator<NameValuePair>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(NameValuePair o1, NameValuePair o2) {
    return(o1.getName().compareTo(o2.getName()));
   }
  });`

Comment: In case the key is of integer type, the comparator `Comparator.comparingInt(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getKey()))` can be used to keep order based on integer value